# Lavaan modification indices suggest to include in the model the correlations between variables produced by indprod, should I do it?

Tags: r, interaction, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan

I am testing a moderated mediation with lavaan. I used indprod to calculate the interaction term

```
modmediation <- indProd(db2, var1=22:27, var2=33:35, match=F, doubleMC=T)
```

then I created the model

```
mod1.path <- "
VAR1 =~ var1item1 + var1item2 + var1item3
VAR2 =~ var2item1 + var2item2 + var2item3 +
        var2item4 + var2item5 + var2item6
MEDIATOR =~ var3item1 + var3item2 + var3item3 +
            var3item4 + var3item5 + var3item6 +
            var3item7 + var3item8
VAR1xVAR2 =~ var2item1.var1item1 + var2item1.var1item2 + 
             var2item1.var1item3 + var2item2.var1item1 + 
             var2item2.var1item2 + var2item2.var1item3 + 
             var2item3.var1item1 + var2item3.var1item2 + 
             var2item3.var1item3 + var2item4.var1item1 +
             var2item4.var1item2 + var2item4.var1item3 + 
             var2item5.var1item1 + var2item5.var1item2 + 
             var2item5.var1item3 + var2item6.var1item1 + 
             var2item6.var1item2 + var2item6.var1item3
DEPENDENT =~ var4item1 + var4item2 + var4item3 + var4item4 +
             var4item5 + var4item6 + var4item7 + var4item8 +
             var4item9
MEDIATOR ~ a * VAR1 + VAR2 + VAR1xVAR2
DEPENDENT ~ b * MEDIATOR + cp*VAR1
ab:=a*b
totaleffect:=(ab+cp)
"
```

Fit indices are not great.
CFI=0.67
TLI=0.65
RMSEA=0.12
SRMR=0.07

Checking the estimated variances, I notice that 9 of the 18 variables created by the indprod function (var2item1.var1item1, var2item1.var1item2 etc) have a negative estimate in the latent variables table.
Moreover, if I check the modificationindices, estimating the indprod items as covariating between each other seems to be by far the best way to improve the model (even though the improvements are not impressive overall).

Expecting the indprod items to covariate makes sense of course since these items are different product combinations of the same items, but does this make any sense theoretically?

Comment: I'm not familiar with indprod. But that's a pretty poorly fitting model. But the fit indices are weird. SRMR is almost OK. CFI is dreadful. RMSEA is bad.  What is your sample size?

Comment: Oh, indprod just multiplies stuff. Do you have a citation for this sort of model?

Comment: Sample size is 478. I do not have a citation for this kind of model, it makes sense theoretically and this seemed to me the only way to test it in lavaan. I do not know of any other way to test a mediated moderation in lavaan.

Comment: I am not convinced that it makes theoretical sense to use the products of indicators of two latent variables as indicators of a third latent variable. A model with an latent variable that has 18 indicators is not going to fit well at the best of times, but given that multiple indicators have the root variables, unidimensionality seems very unlikely.

Comment: I understand your concerns and I agree, but how would you do it instead? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know of an way to model interactions of latent variables in lavaan. There's some work by Dan Bauer looking at how to use latent classes in Mplus to model non-linear effects that might be modifiable. But (IMHO) modeling interactions of latents in a straightforward way is an unsolved problem.